# Отсортировать коллекцию по двум полям

Tags: java, javafx, сортировка, list

Имеется следующий код:

```
public Product() {}

public Integer getCod() {
    return cod;
}

public void setCod(Integer cod) {
    this.cod = cod;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Double getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}

public Integer getBatchQuantity() {
    return batchQuantity;
}

public void setBatchQuantity(Integer batchQuantity) {
    this.batchQuantity = batchQuantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "cod=" + cod +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", number=" + number +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", price=" + price +
            ", discount=" + discount +
            ", batchQuantity=" + batchQuantity +
            '}';
}
}
```

И следующий код кнопки сортировщика:

```
/**
 * Кнопка сортировщик
 */
@FXML
public void onSortAction() {
    loadData();
    message.setText("");
    // сортировка по возрастанию названия и цены
    if (nameAsc.isSelected() == true && priceAsc.isSelected() == true) {
        List sortedProductList = productList.stream().sorted((o1, o2) ->
                -o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        sortedProductList = productList.stream().sorted((o1, o2) ->
                -o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        productList = sortedProductList;
    }
}
```

По одному полю я смог отсортировать, как сделать так чтобы по обоим полям можно было сортировать данный список?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для сортировки по нескольким полям удобно использовать компараторы ([`java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) с их цепочками вызовов типа `comparing().thenComparing().thenComparing()...`

[Описание метода `thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)

да и код можно подсократить, не теряя в его понятности.
вот мой вариант функции:

```
public void onSortAction() {
    loadData();
    message.setText("");
    // сортировка по возрастанию названия и цены
    // сначала сравниваются названия, при равенстве названий сравниваются цены
    if (nameAsc.isSelected() == true && priceAsc.isSelected() == true) {
        List sortedProductList = productList.stream().sorted(
            Comparator.comparing(Product::getName).thenComparing(Product::getPrice)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        productList = sortedProductList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это отлично, но с компараторами я так и не разобрался(((( если есть ресурс или статья- буду признателен

Comment: Признаться, я сам не так давно изучаю язык Java.
О компараторах обзорно читал в книге "Java 8 - Полное руководство" (Герберт Шилдт) и в доках к Java.
Можете погуглить по фразе "компараторы в Java", в выдаче есть полезные статьи.

Answer (score 6):

**Дополнение:** обратите внимание на [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673586/227016), на мой взгляд он понятнее и удобнее.

Вам нужно решить, какой из ключей является главным при сортировке, и сначала сравнивать объекты по этому ключу, а при равенстве главных ключей сравнивать второстепенные ключи. Ниже приведён код в предположении, что главным ключом является поле «название».

```
public void onSortAction() {
    loadData();
    message.setText("");
    // сортировка по возрастанию названия и цены
    // сначала сравниваются названия, при равенстве названий сравниваются цены
    if (nameAsc.isSelected() == true && priceAsc.isSelected() == true) {
        List sortedProductList = productList.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
            int compareNames = -o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            return compareNames != 0
                    ? compareNames
                    : -o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        productList = sortedProductList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61637/discussion-on-answer-by-diraria-----).